# how to invoke http method using dp:url-open function

Tags: xslt, ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

question : how to invoke http method (GET,POST,CREATE & DELETE) using IBM Datapower dp:url-open function in XSLT language

requirement : code in xslt and step by step process theory in short ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be tedious if you don't learn to read the documentation... Your question has the clear answer in the docs, here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateways/10.0.1?topic=elements-dpurl-open

However, trying to explain what's going on in a bit more detail as for the command:

```
<dp:url-open
  target="URL"
  response="xml | binaryNode | ignore | responsecode | responsecode-binary | responsecode-ignore"
  resolve-mode="xml | swa"
  base-uri-node="nodeset"
  data-type="xml | base64 | filename"
  http-headers="nodeset"
  content-type="contentType"
  ssl-proxy="client:profile"
  timeout="seconds"
  http-method="get | patch | post | put | delete | head"
  options="options">
</dp:url-open>
```

The first thing you need is obviously the URL. This can be a string or a variable:

```
target="https://google.com"
target="{$url_variable}"
```

The default method is `GET` but for any other you'd need to set the `http-method` parameter. To post data and fetch the response in a variable you'd use:

```
<xsl:variable name="jsp-response">
  <dp:url-open target="http://www.datapower.com/application.jsp">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$some-nodes">
  </dp:url-open>
</xsl:variable>
```

This would make a `HTTP POST` request sending the data (body) found in the `$some-nodes` variable.