# Fetch JSON from API using XSLT

Tags: json, api, saxon, xslt-3.0

I need to fetch a JSON file from an [API](http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087) using XSLT 3, something like this would be in python:

```py
    import urllib.request, json 
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087") as url:
        data = json.load(url)
        print(data)
```

First I tried it with `doc('http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087')` but as the function expects an XML document I'm getting this error:

> Content is not allowed in prolog.

Otherwise it seems that this extension [dp:url-open](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateway/2018.4?topic=elements-dpurl-open) would yield the needed result (cf. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434581/how-to-invoke-http-method-using-dpurl-open-function)). However, when invoking an XSLT transformation using Saxon EE 11.4 I'm getting this error:

> Unknown extension instruction

I suppose that the extension should be somehow declared for Saxon (?)
I've searched in the  Saxon documentation like this [section](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensibility/)
but did not find what I need.

Here is my test XSLT:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd dme functx dp" version="3.0"
      xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dme="http://www.mozarteum.at/ns/dme"
      xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
      xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xpath-default-namespace="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
    
   <template match="/">
      <variable name="test">
        <dp:url-open target="http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087"/>
      </variable>
    <copy-of select="$test"/>
  </template>
    
    </stylesheet>
```

P.S. I'm invoking the transformation using oXygen XML editor 25.0, build 2023013006.

Comment: dp:url-open() is a vendor extension in the IBM Datapower XSLT processor. I'm afraid I have no idea what it does, so I have no idea what the Saxon equivalent might be. But Martin Honnen's answer tells you (very briefly!) how to access JSON resources using standard XSLT 3.0 constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get JSON from that API you can use `json-doc('http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087')` to have an XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 XDM map or array in your XSLT code. To select/find data in XDM maps/arrays see https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#new-xpath-3.1-operators or the similar sections in the XPath 3.1 spec on arrays and maps and using the lookup operator https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-lookup.

If you want an XML representation of the JSON use `unparsed-text('http://dme-intern.mozarteum.local/digital-editions/api/work-info/4087') => json-to-xml()` instead.

Comment: Thank you!
That is what I was searching for.